# Why does appentTo work while append doesn't?

Tags: jquery, iframe

So, I'm injecting styling into an iframe via a textbox and I'm curious why appendTo works while append doesn't. I was under the impression that these were the same, other than small performance differences:

```
var contents = $('iframe').contents();
var body = contents.find('body');

var styleTag = $('<style>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));
// BROKEN??? = contents.find('head').append($('<style>'));

$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.attr('class') === 'html') {
    body.html($this.val());
  } else {
    styleTag.text($this.val());
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems to work fine as far as I can tell. Can you explain in what way it fails to work?

Comment: If you where doing `var styleTag = contents.find('head').append($('<style>'));` then the styleTag object would not be equal to the new style object you create. Alternatively you could create the new style element : `var styleTag = $('<style>');` and then append that to the iframe : `contents.find('head').append(styleTag);`. That should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

From the oficial documentation:

[.appendTo( target ):](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

[.append( content [, content ] ):](http://api.jquery.com/append/) Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of how you are using the methods is incorrect. The way you are using them you are assuming both `.append($('<style>');` and `$('<style>').appendTo(...);` return the newly created `<style>` element.

This assumption is incorrect.

The line `var styleTag = $('<style>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));` **will** return the newly created style element.

However the line `var styleTag = contents.find('head').append($('<style>'));` returns the `head` object of the IFrame.

A way around this is to create the `<style>` element first and then append it to the IFrame :

```
var contents = $('iframe').contents();
var body = contents.find('body');

var styleTag = $('<style>');
contents.find('head').append(styleTag);
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks for the thorough answer. I'd rep you, but still new to the site :(

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions, append and appendTo have the same functionality. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target.

eg below two statements add a span tag to div. After execution, the markup of both the divs will be exactly same.

```
$('<span>').appendTo(contents.find('#div1'));
contents.find('#div2').append($('<span>'));
```